# How can I make a dialog box floating while working on the window?

Tags: mapbasic, dialog

I would like to have a floating dialog box just like the Named Views.mbx

How could make my existing dialog box float while working on other window?

Answer (score 2):

You'll have to create your dialog outside of MapBasic, for instance thru C# or VB.NET.
Then you can call the method in your external application or assembly from MapBasic.

Look in the Samples folder in your MapBasic installation folder: Samples\DOTNET\NAMEDVIEWS

Here you'll find the source code for the Named Views application

Comment: So i need to learn another program for it.. Can i edit the existing sample? Thanks Peter..

Comment: You can edit the existing samples and in that way learn from them. But do make sure that you change things that are specific to these application so that your application won't interfer with the other application in case you want to run them at the same time or on the same computer. Things to look out for could be configuration file names etc